# Can't access parent's attributes using super initialisation in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I have parent class `Gauge`, which records video from web camera(OpenCV) in separate thread in `while`-loop . All the frames are saved as class attribute and I can easily see them being in the `Gauge`. Whenever I try to access `Gauge`'s frames from child class using  inheritance I become the error, saying AttributeError: `'Video' object has no attribute 'frame'` . Here is the snippets:

```
class Gauge(object):
    def __init__(self):
       
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
        if self.capture.isOpened():
            print("opened camera")
        self.video_thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.video_thread.name='video thread'
        self.video_thread.daemon = True
        self.video_thread.start()
     
    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
                 

class Video(Gauge):
    def __init__(self, master):     
        super(Video, self).__init__()
     #skipping unimportant lines...
        while True:
            image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #AttributeError!!
            image = cv2.resize(image,(round(self.master.winfo_width()/2-20),round(self.master.winfo_height()-10)),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            image = Image.fromarray(image)
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
           
            self.labelVideo.configure(image=image)
            self.labelVideo.image=image
```

Comment: Has `self.capture.isOpened()` returned `True` yet? If not, `self.frame` hasn't been created yet.

Comment: @tdelaney `update` gets called from a thread started in `Gauge.__init__`, but it's not at all clear that a race condition isn't to blame.

Comment: @chepner yes, it‘s true and I see even how camera lights are turned on

Comment: @chepner - oh, right. I think I'm blind.

Comment: I would have `update` write to, and `Video.__init__` read from, a `Queue` rather than trying to use the object itself as a queue. (I would also not be doing anywhere near so much I/O inside `__init__`. Initialize the object first, *then* call some methods that can start separate threads.

Comment: @tdelaney It took me at least a couple of minutes to tease out what this code is doing.

Comment: @chepner could you post the answer please? Im not an expert in Python and have little idea about Queue() 

Comment: +1 on @chepner 's suggestion for a Queue. The background thread could change `self.frame` at any time while the foreground thread is using it. As a minimum, `self.frame` should be protected by a mutex.

Comment: @chepner please, by this project I have no external assistance, so your answer would be    essential for me

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely due to `Video.__init__` trying to access `self.frame` before the thread running `Gauge.update` can create it. You also don't want to be running an infinite loop inside `Video.__init__`. It's also not clear that `Video` should be a subclass of `Gauge` at all, but I would try something like

```
from queue import Queue


class Gauge(object):
    def __init__(self, q: Queue):
       
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
        if self.capture.isOpened():
            print("opened camera")
        self.video_thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=(q,))
        self.video_thread.name='video thread'
        self.video_thread.daemon = True
        self.video_thread.start()
     
    # Stores captures in a queue for someone to consume
    def update(self, q):
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                q.put(self.capture.read())
                 

class Video(Gauge):
    def __init__(self, master):  
        self.q = Queue()   
        super(Video, self).__init__(self.q)

    def capture_images(self):
    
        while True:
            # Wait until a capture is available
            status, frame = self.q.get()

            # Then use the capture
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = cv2.resize(image,(round(self.master.winfo_width()/2-20),round(self.master.winfo_height()-10)),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            image = Image.fromarray(image)
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
           
            self.labelVideo.configure(image=image)
            self.labelVideo.image=image

    v = Video()
    v.capture_images()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It helped me a lot. But I am confused with the passing `q` into `.__init__()`. I tried to pass `self.q`, but still getting error. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I modified `Gauge` under the assumption that it may or may not be subclassed. Since whoever is instantiating `Gauge` will likely be the one to be consuming the contents of the queue, I leave it to them to supply the queue that `Gauge.update` will use. It gets passed to `Gauge.__init__` because that's where the thread that will call `update` is created.